# How to change font for the CodeMirror editor

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, codemirror

I am trying to change font-family and font-size of my CodeMirror editor. I tried changing it by setting the according CSS attributes but it does not seem to work for me:

```
.codemirror-textarea {
    font-family: Arial, monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Do I have to import something in order to achieve this or might I have to edit the libraries CSS file directly? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try setting the CSS on:

```
.CodeMirror {
font-family: Arial, monospace;
font-size: 16px;
}
```

This selects the element that contains all the formatted code.

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it for me.

Comment: I will tag this as an answer as soon as I am able to.

Comment: Is there a way to inherit a class or styles from the textarea?

Comment: font family doesn't change

Comment: I know I'm late to the party Daniel, but the version I'm using requires a wildcard: `.CodeMirror * { ... }`

Answer (score 12):

Just to follow-up on the accepted answer, the version of CodeMirror I'm using (5.55.0 at the time of posting) requires a wildcard:

```css
.CodeMirror * {
/*          ^
*/
  font-family: Arial, monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Or add an extension

```js
const customTheme = EditorView.theme({
    '&': {
        font:"'JetBrains Mono', monospace",
    }
})

const startState = EditorState.create({
    doc: page.text,
    extensions: [
        customTheme,
        // ...
    ]
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Or, like this if you want to do it from JavaScript:

```
editor.getWrapperElement().style["font-size"] = size+"px";
editor.refresh();
```